# Wrapping a c++ singleton with cython

Tags: cython

Using Cython to wrap some parts from a C++ API to python, I'm having misunderstandings that I couldn't fix by search similar questions. I like to access a Factory class that has the constructors private and a public method GetInstance.

```cpp
namespace cpplibrary
{
    class CppFactory
    {
    public:
        static CppFactory& GetInstance();
    private:
        CppFactory(void);
        CppFactory( const CppFactory& );
    };
}
```

I'm trying a cython code like:

```py
cdef extern from "cppFactory.h" namespace "cpplibrary":
    cdef cppclass CppFactory:
        CppFactory() except +
        CppFactory& GetInstance()

cdef class PyFactory:
    cdef CppFactory* _thisptr
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._thisptr = GetInstance()
```

I've check with as many variants as I thought. With and without the declaration of the constructor in the *extern*. With different ways to define the *_thisptr* from different posted examples. And so on. But I couldn't find a singleton example like this.

Where is the mistake I can't see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got two issues:

1) How to wrap static methods: [the recommended way](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/xaErUq2yY0s) is to declare the function outside the class, and use a string to tell Cython what name it should use in C++

2) The assignment to `thisptr`, where you just need to use `&` to get a pointer from the reference.

Code:

```
cdef extern from "cppFactory.h" namespace "cpplibrary":
    cdef cppclass CppFactory:
        CppFactory() except +

    # declare outside the class and use a string to specify name
    # unfortunately this doesn't seem to play well with namespace
    # so we need to specify it again
    cdef CppFactory& CppFactory_GetInstance "cpplibrary::CppFactory::GetInstance"()

cdef class PyFactory:
    cdef CppFactory* _thisptr
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._thisptr = &CppFactory_GetInstance()
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the problem is indeed to wrap a static method (here `Getinstance()`).

You can do that by using the cython `@staticmethod` decorator (see Cython's doc [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#static-member-method)):

```
cdef extern from "cppFactory.h" namespace "cpplibrary":
    cdef cppclass CppFactory:
        @staticmember
        CppFactory& GetInstance()
```

Then, the .pyx can be:

```
cdef class PyFactory:
    cdef CppFactory* _thisptr
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._thisptr = new CppFactory()
```